# Share application "link" in Android

Tags: android, share

I want my application user to be able to share/recommend my app to other users. I use the ACTION_SEND intent. I add plain text saying something along the lines of: install this cool application. But I can't find a way to enable users to directly go to the install screen of market place for instance. All I can provide them with is a web link or some text.
In other words I am looking for a very direct way for android users to have my app installed.

Thanks for any help/pointers,

Thomas

Answer (score 321, accepted):

This will let you choose from email, whatsapp or whatever.

```
try { 
    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
    String shareMessage= "\nLet me recommend you this application\n\n";
    shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +"\n\n";
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);  
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "choose one"));
} catch(Exception e) { 
    //e.toString();
}
```

Comment: Firebase share application. read more about
https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/android

Comment: Why is this wrapped in a try/catch block ?

Comment: Android loves to make so many changes in their updates that who knows if this code will fail in a future update

Comment: @Ton How can I send app icon image along with Subject and text.

Comment: do it on background thread , it is somehow heavy for main thread. users won't feel the lag on background thread

Comment: Showing "Can't attach empty file", when we choose gmail.

Comment: @VaheGharibyan Firebase Invites is now deprecated https://firebase.google.com/docs/invites/deprecation.

Comment: But what if I want reward my user on every user? In that case, I need a listener to check whether the invitation has been successfully sent or not.

Comment: In the above code, can we add a listener or something like that to check whether an invite has really been sent or not?

Answer (score 47):

You can use also **ShareCompat** class from support library.

```
ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
    .setType("text/plain")
    .setChooserTitle("Chooser title")
    .setText("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + activity.getPackageName())
    .startChooser();
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ShareCompat.html

Comment: could we set language also?  I know it would be simple as appending `&hl` tag to the url but just curious if it is available in library like setLang or something.

Comment: Please always use https instead of http in links.

Comment: this is best answer but it is deprecated. removing .from will resolve it.

Answer (score 21):

Thomas,

You would want to provide your users with a `market://` link which will bring them directly to the details page of your app.  The following is from developer.android.com:

> Loading an application's Details page
>
> In Android Market, every application
>   has a Details page that provides an
>   overview of the application for users.
>   For example, the page includes a short
>   description of the app and screen
>   shots of it in use, if supplied by the
>   developer, as well as feedback from
>   users and information about the
>   developer. The Details page also
>   includes an "Install" button that lets
>   the user trigger the download/purchase
>   of the application.
>
> If you want to refer the user to a
>   specific application, your
>   application can take the user directly
>   to the application's Details page. To
>   do so, your application sends an
>   ACTION_VIEW Intent that includes a URI
>   and query parameter in this format:
>
> market://details?id=
>
> In this case, the packagename
>   parameter is target application's
>   fully qualified package name, as
>   declared in the package attribute of
>   the manifest element in the
>   application's manifest file. For
>   example:
>
> market://details?id=com.example.android.jetboy

Source: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

Comment: +1 for the link. That looks good. As I want the user to share I still need to use the ACTION_SEND and add the market link in my text. If the user clicks on it it shoudl redirect him to the install page. Sounds good I have to try it. Let me know if I understood you right.

Comment: Yeah you can use the market link in the text of an ACTION_SEND, it will only work if clicked on while on an android device though.

Comment: but this link will not open the market link if we use ACTION_SEND, link will stay there as a simple text. but the link was helpful to open market WITH ACTION_VIEW.

Answer (score 15):

Call this method:

```
public static void shareApp(Context context)
{
    final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out the App at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    context.startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```

Answer (score 12):

To be more exact

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
   intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.android.example"));
   startActivity(intent);
```

or if you want to share your other apps from your dev. account you can do something like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Your_Publisher_Name"));
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 11):

To automatically fill in the application name and application id you could use this:

```
int applicationNameId = context.getApplicationInfo().labelRes;
final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, activity.getString(applicationNameId));
String text = "Install this cool application: ";
String link = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName;
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text + " " + link);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share link:"));
```

Answer (score 11):

Share application with title is you app_name, content is your application link

```
fun shareApp(context: Context) {
    val appPackageName = BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
    val appName = context.getString(R.string.app_name)
    val shareBodyText = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=$appPackageName"

    val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND).apply {
        type = "text/plain"
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, appName)
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBodyText)
    }
    context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null))
}
```

Comment: how to share app icon

Comment: can I use "applicationContext" instead of passing context?

Answer (score 6):

I know this question has been answered, but I would like to share an alternate solution:

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
String shareSubText = "WhatsApp - The Great Chat App";
String shareBodyText = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp&hl=en";
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, shareSubText);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareBodyText);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share With"));
```

Answer (score 3):

finally, this code is worked for me to open the email client from android device. 
try this snippet.

```
Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    Uri data = Uri.parse("mailto:?subject=" + "Feedback" + "&body=" + "Write Feedback here....." + "&to=" + "someone@example.com");
                    testIntent.setData(data);
                    startActivity(testIntent);
```

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin extension for share action. You can share whatever you want e.g. link

```
fun Context.share(text: String) =
    this.startActivity(Intent().apply {
        action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text)
        type = "text/plain"
    })
```

Usage

```
context.share("Check https://stackoverflow.com")
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send) in 2021 preferred way is

```
fun shareTextToOtherApps(message: String) {
        val sendIntent: Intent = Intent().apply {
            action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
            putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, message)
            type = "text/plain"
        }

        val shareIntent = Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, null)
        startActivity(shareIntent)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually the best way to sheared you app between users , google (firebase) proved new technology Firebase Dynamic Link Through several lines you can make it 
this is  documentation
 https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/
and the code is

```
  Uri dynamicLinkUri = dynamicLink.getUri();
      Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
            .setLink(Uri.parse("https://www.google.jo/"))
            .setDynamicLinkDomain("rw4r7.app.goo.gl")
            .buildShortDynamicLink()
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Short link created
                        Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                        Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();
                        Intent intent = new Intent();
                        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  shortLink.toString());
                        intent.setType("text/plain");
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        // Error
                        // ...
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try { 
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Your Application name");
String shareMessage= "\n Your Message \n\n";
shareMessage = shareMessage + "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID +"\n\n";
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shareMessage);  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "choose one"));
} catch(Exception e) { 
//e.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Linh answer is almost good but causing a crash because of the missing FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK, here is what worked for me

```
    public static void shareApp(Context context) {
    final String appPackageName = context.getPackageName();
    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out the App at: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + appPackageName);
    sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
    context.startActivity(sendIntent);
}
```