# How to get share text in web view app

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, share

I have an Android Web View app and i have added share action in it. but i want it to send text from my web view to any app.

please help me to fix this issue.

here is the code it is share the **DEMO XYZ** text But i want to share this text which is showing in href

> `<a href="share://send?text=hello this is demo testing">Share</a>`

how can i do this please help me.

```
 if (url!=null && url.startsWith ("share://"))
    }
    Intent intent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setType("text/plain")
    intent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"DEMO XYZ");
    view.getContext().startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"share"));
    return true;
    }
```

In my website link i am using

```
<a href="share://send?text=hello this is demo testing">Share</a>
```

Comment: You want to share text to an other app what does that means?

Comment: i mean i am getting text from web and i want to share it to different app like whatsapp ,sms,imo and more...

Comment: Did you read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969217/share-application-link-in-android