# Deep Linking sharing not working with facebook

Tags: android, facebook, deep-linking

I am sharing the content of my using the method from this question.

[Share application "link" in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4969217/share-application-link-in-android)

```
try { 
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);  
i.setType("text/plain");
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "My application name");
String sAux = "\nLet open the content of my app\n\n";
sAux = sAux + "https://myApp//content \n\n";
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, sAux);  
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "choose one"));
   } catch(Exception e) { 
    //e.toString();
}
```

The method work for all the apps expect facebook. 
All other app share simple text with given message "Let open the content of my app" and link to the app. If the app is installed the conent is opened in app.

But facebook somehow converts text given in Intent which look like this:
[image]

but in my case there is not picture and description only link and the content is opened by facebook webBrowser instead by my app.

Can you explain me how can I share the link to my app on facebook? I need thet when the user click on the share button all installed application which are can share the content are listed.

Comment: Facebook does not allow you to specify the message of a share for the user, they have to type that in themselves. And they don’t allow specifying any properties of the shared link (title, description, thumbnail, …) at run-time any more either, all that info will be taken from the Open Graph meta tags the shared URL returns.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but how can I force facebook to open my app from shared URL and put the description in Open Grahp meta tags?

Comment: Start here, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/applinks/